# Opening text file and replacing two strings in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, file, text

I need to replace two seperate strings in a text file and subsequently save the altered version as a new text file.

So far I have the following code:

```
fid = fopen('original_file.txt','rt') ;
X = fread(fid) ;
fclose(fid) ;
X = char(X.') ;

Y = strrep(X, 'results1.csv', 'results2.csv') ;
Z = strrep(X, 'plot1', 'plot2') ;
fid2 = fopen('new_file.txt','wt') ;
fwrite(fid2,Y) ;
fwrite(fid2,Z) ;

fclose (fid2) ;
```

The problem with this code is that it simply doubles the length of the text file - In other words the `new_file.txt` has twice as many lines as `original_file.txt`.

First the content is written with `results1.csv` changed to `results2.csv` then the same content is appended with `plot1` changed to `plot2`.

Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating two variables `Y` and `Z` and writing both variables to `new_file.txt`. To replace two separate strings, use the strrep function twice:

```
fid = fopen('original_file.txt','rt') ;
X = fread(fid) ;
fclose(fid) ;
X = char(X.') ;

Y = strrep(X, 'results1.csv', 'results2.csv') ;
Z = strrep(Y, 'plot1', 'plot2') ; % replace the second string, after the first replacement
fid2 = fopen('new_file.txt','wt') ;
fwrite(fid2,Z) ; % write just Z, with both replacements

fclose (fid2) ;
```